# CollectionViewCells not displaying in middle on iPhone 13 Pro only

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, ios15

An issue with our collection view that displays the user's camera roll has appeared specifically on the iPhone 13 Pro. This includes the simulator and real device.

The layout of the cells is acting like there's a missing column in the collection view. This bug does not occur on models prior such as 12 Pro Max or SE 2nd gen.

The layout I am using is the "UICollectionViewFlowLayout" or "Flow" layout. I am wondering if this is an iOS 15 or Xcode 13 issue, or did something change elsewhere.

Here are some screenshots that showcase the issue:

iPhone 13 Pro:

[image: iPhone 13 pro screenshot]

iPhone 12 Pro Max:

[image]

The same code renders both of these outputs...

What could be causing this problem or where to look?

**UPDATE:**

The width is calculated properly:

```
let numberOfColumn = CGFloat(configure.numberOfColumn)
let width = (view.frame.size.width - (5 * (numberOfColumn - 1))) / numberOfColumn
```

As you will see in the following ss, when I select a cell (orange bordeR) it is normal size, the cell size doesn't seem to be the issue. When I click on the empty space in the middle, it does nothing, there is no cell there.

[image]

Comment: Adjust the cell size.

Comment: You also need to adjust the central gap. Consider it for different devices.

Comment: Do you have a static width? It should be something like (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / numberOfHorizontalItems) - spacing - (leading + trailing)/numberOfHorizontalItems

Comment: I updated the question, it doesn't seem to be a cell size issue, more like index or layout issue.

Comment: Any ideas? Number if columns is const 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was the cell size being off by a fraction!

```
let count = CGFloat(configure.numberOfColumn) // value is always 3
let width = floor((view.frame.size.width - (5 * (count - 1))) / count)
```

Calling `floor()` on the width fixed the issue, 3 cells can now fit in screen width on 13 Pro and other models.